# Get AD User info using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, attributes

I'm trying to get a bunch of Active Directory attributes using PowerShell for a list of users. I'm importing the list of users into a variable and then use a ForEach loop to go through each user. Here's what the script looks like so far:

```
$Users=Get-Content "C:\Project\NewUSers\FirstBatch.txt"
$UserInfo = foreach($User in $Users) 
{
  Get-ADUser $User -properties DisplayName,PasswordLastSet,whencreated | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName,PasswordLastSet,WhenCreated
}
$UserInfo
```

However, when I run the script, I get the following error message:

> Select-Object : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ExpandProperty'. Specified method is not supported.
>   At line:4 char:104
>   + ... ExpandProperty DisplayName,PasswordLastSet
>   +                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

The script does run when I only retrieve a signal attribute. So if I were to change the code to this, it'll work and give me the value to those attributes:

```
Get-ADUser $User -properties DisplayName,PasswordLastSet,whencreated | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PasswordLastSet
```

Would anyone be able to point out where the issue may be? Any other suggestion would also be welcome. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use -ExpandObject with these properties, they're all simple types like string and datetime. -ExpandObject is used to display all the properties of an object or convert the contents of an array into a string.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx

As always with powershell there are many ways to achieve the same result, the following to examples will achieve the desired outcome.

> Using the pipeline

```
$Users=Get-Content "C:\Project\NewUSers\FirstBatch.txt"
$UserInfo = $Users | foreach-object {Get-ADUser $_ -properties DisplayName,PasswordLastSet,whencreated} | Select DisplayName, PasswordLastSet, WhenCreated
$UserInfo
```

> Using standard iteration

```
$Users = Get-Content "C:\Project\NewUSers\FirstBatch.txt"
$UserInfo = foreach($User in $Users) 
{
  Get-ADUser $User -properties DisplayName,PasswordLastSet,whencreated | Select-Object DisplayName,PasswordLastSet,WhenCreated
}
$UserInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can't Expand multiple properties, You can create an array and add those info into it, like this:

```
$Array = @() ## this array will hold all the data
$Users=Get-Content "C:\Project\NewUSers\FirstBatch.txt"

foreach($User in $Users) 
{
  $User = Get-ADUser $User -properties DisplayName,PasswordLastSet,whencreated 
  $Result = "" | Select DisplayName,PasswordLastSet,WhenCreated ## this will create a single user data object
  $Result.DisplayName = $User.DisplayName
  $Result.PasswordLastSet = $User.PasswordLastSet
  $Result.WhenCreated = $User.WhenCreated
  $Array += $Result ## this will add the single user data into the array
}

$Array
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only set a single object or an array for the switch -ExpandProperty. For the specified parameters (DisplayName,PasswordLastSet,WhenCreated) you don't need to specify ExpandProperty switch because they are single value properties.

Run your code but without ExpandProperty:

```
 $Users=Get-Content "C:\Project\NewUSers\FirstBatch.txt"
$array = @()
foreach($User in $Users) 
{
  $aduser = Get-ADUser $User -properties DisplayName,PasswordLastSet,whencreated 
  $array += $aduser
}

$array| select DisplayName,PasswordLastSet,whencreated |export-csv -Path "C:\Project\NewUSers\users.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you. One last question: how do I go about exporting this data into Excel? I tried Export-CSV but the data it produced in the file is all gibberish and nothing like what appears within PowerShell. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1013264 - I have updated my post try and let me know

Comment: Thanks. I get this error for the export part:

Export-Csv : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'Export-Csv C' does not exist.
At line:9 char:95
+ ... rdchangeflag | Export-Csv -Path "Export-Csv C:\Project\ELI.csv" -NoTypeInformati ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Export-Csv C:String) [Export-Csv], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Comment: Look in the error the path that you have put after -Path switch is "-Path "Export-Csv C:\Project\ELI.csv"